# My Ex-Employer wanted me back

Tags: india, employer

Just checking with you people if it is good to go back to the ex employer, i am young professional with 2.5 years of work experience, i have switched from my first company(where i joined as a fresher) an year back with all formalities and good will.

My ex-manager(he is promoted to some good position now) has called me and asking me if i am interested in coming back because he likes my work and they are in search of good people so he was just checking with their good ex-employees, regarding my current employer i am working fine there, promoted and got good raise as well, however the worst thing which i am facing here is they don't stick with their words, they do the things but after stretching it too much.

They are calling me back and ready to consider my requirements, do you think it would be a good deal?

Let me know your comments.

Thanks in advance,
Faaiz

Comment: We can't tell you what to do with your life. IMHO this is off topic. Perhaps you may have a valid question here if you were to rephrase it while focusing on the risks/benefits of coming back to a former employer?

Comment: @MrFox you can always vote to close if you feel a question is off topic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each person's situation is different but I can tell you from my experience that I did that and it worked really well. This is quite different than accepting a counter offer, in my opinion. They know you, your work, your skills and they think it would be good to have you working with them.

You have some leverage, don't over exercise it but try to get a good and balanced deal out of it.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of it depends on why you left initially, and if those same circumstances will still be there.

As user1220 says, it is a lot different from a counteroffer, in that a counteroffer is often just more money, and they then know you want to leave.  In this case, they want you back, and that often can work out very well.

Did you leave simply to get more money?  Did you otherwise respect the company, consider your manager a good one, have good working conditions, enough challenges, and decent coworkers?  If not, will those things be something that has now changed?  If not, is it still better than where you are now?

You are in a good position, because you're considering a job where you know a lot about the conditions and the company.  Think about all that you liked and disliked about the job before you left it.  Compare it to what you like and dislike about your current job.  It's like deciding on any other new job, except you have so much more information on how good it is likely to be.